# Create a Sharepoint Calendar with multiple outlook Calendars?

Tags: 2013, calendar, outlook

I am trying to create a calendar on our SP site that has my teams schedules on it. I wanted the information to be pulled directly from Outlook. I tried to use the Calendar Overlay option but it only shows the schedule of the person logged into sharepoint. Is there any way to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.